Neighbor Joining algorithm
I am trying to write a neighbor-joining algorithm myself, but I have an issue with the main loop part. In this example, I would like to loop through 4 .fasta sequences that I have downloaded locally. The loop runs as long as there are more than 4 sequences (clades). It will merge clades until there are exactly 4 clades left.
The code shows no errors and it builds the tree, however, it seems wrong to me since all the branches are equal in size.
# Import necessary libraries

from Bio import SeqIO, AlignIO, Phylo
from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalOmegaCommandline
from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceCalculator
from Bio.Phylo.BaseTree import Clade, Tree
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


# Step 1: Insertion of Sequences
file_paths = [
    "X:\\PROJECT\\whole_env_sequences\\hiv1env-a.fasta",
    "X:\\PROJECT\\whole_env_sequences\\hiv1env-b.fasta",
    "X:\\PROJECT\\whole_env_sequences\\hiv1env-c.fasta",
    "X:\\PROJECT\\whole_env_sequences\\hiv1env-d.fasta"
]
combined_fasta = "X:\\PROJECT\\combined_sequences.fasta"

# Initialize an empty list to store all sequences
all_sequences = []

# Parse each file and append the sequences to the list
for file_path in file_paths:
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"The file {file_path} does not exist.")
    sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(file_path, "fasta"))
    all_sequences.extend(sequences)

# Write all sequences to the combined FASTA file
with open(combined_fasta, "w") as output_handle:
    SeqIO.write(all_sequences, output_handle, "fasta")

print(f"Total sequences written to combined file: {len(all_sequences)}")

print(combined_fasta)

print('Sequences assembly is finished -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

# Step 2: Multiple Sequence Alignment
# Define the Clustal Omega command line
clustalomega_cline = ClustalOmegaCommandline(
    cmd="E:\\clustal-omega-1.2.2-win64\\clustalo.exe",
    infile=combined_fasta,
    outfile="X:\\PROJECT\\aligned_sequences.aln",
    verbose=True,
    auto=True,
    force=True  # Add the force option to overwrite existing files
)

# Run Clustal Omega alignment and capture the output and errors
stdout, stderr = clustalomega_cline()

# Print output and error information
print("Standard Output:", stdout)
print("Standard Error:", stderr)

# Check if alignment file was created successfully
aligned_file = "X:\\PROJECT\\aligned_sequences.aln"
if not os.path.exists(aligned_file):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"The alignment file {aligned_file} was not created. Please check Clustal Omega command.")

# Read the alignment
alignment = AlignIO.read(aligned_file, "fasta")

# print(alignment)

print('ClustalO is finished -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

# Step 3: Compute Distance Matrix ( a table that shows how different or similar sequences are from one another )

# The identity model calculates distances based on the proportion of identical positions between sequences.
calculator = DistanceCalculator('identity')

# computation of distance matrix
dm = calculator.get_distance(alignment)

# Convert the Bio.Phylo distance matrix to a numpy array (easier to manipulate)
def to_numpy_matrix(dm):
    matrix = np.zeros((len(dm), len(dm)))
    for i, key1 in enumerate(dm.names):
        for j, key2 in enumerate(dm.names):
            matrix[i, j] = dm[key1, key2]
    return matrix, dm.names

D, names = to_numpy_matrix(dm)

print('D-distance', D)
print('NAMES', names)


print('Distance Matrix is calculated -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')


# Step 4a: Neighbor Joining Algorithm
def neighbor_joining(D, names):
    n = len(D)
    nodes = {i: Clade(name=names[i]) for i in range(n)}
    all_clades = {i: nodes[i] for i in range(n)}

    while n > len(file_paths):
        # Debug: Check the number of sequences
        print(f"Current number of sequences (n): {n}")
        
        # Compute r(i) - net divergence for each sequence
        r = np.sum(D, axis=1)  # This gives the sum of distances for each sequence
        
        # Debug: Check the net divergence
        print("Net Divergence (r):", r)

        # Compute Mij using the exact formula
        M = np.zeros((n, n))
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    M[i, j] = D[i, j] - (r[i] + r[j]) / (n - 2)

        # Debug: Log the M matrix
        print("M-Matrix (exact formula):")
        print(M)

        # Find pair (i, j) with the smallest M[i, j]
        i, j = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(M + np.diag([np.inf] * n)), M.shape)

        # Log the pairs being joined
        print(f"Joining Clades: {names[i]} and {names[j]}")

        # Calculate new distances
        new_row = (D[i, :] + D[j, :] - D[i, j]) / 2
        
        # Update distance matrix
        D = np.delete(D, [i, j], axis=0)
        D = np.delete(D, [i, j], axis=1)

        # Create the new row and append it to the distance matrix
        new_row = np.delete(new_row, [i, j])
        D = np.vstack((D, new_row))
        new_col = np.append(new_row, 0).reshape(-1, 1)
        D = np.hstack((D, new_col))

        # Create new clade
        new_clade = Clade()
        new_clade.clades.append(all_clades[i])
        new_clade.clades.append(all_clades[j])

        # Set the branch lengths appropriately
        new_clade.branch_length = D[-1, -1] / 2 if D[-1, -1] > 0 else 0.001  # Avoid zero length for branches

        # Log the new clade and its branch length
        print(f"New Clade: {new_clade}, Branch Length: {new_clade.branch_length}")

        # Update nodes
        all_clades[n - 2] = new_clade
        del all_clades[i]
        del all_clades[j]

        n -= 1
        print(f"N is now {n}")

    # Handle the remaining 3 clades
    remaining_clades = list(all_clades.values())
    root = Tree(root=Clade())
    root.root.clades.extend(remaining_clades)

    # Ensure that the root's branch length is set
    for clade in root.root.clades:
        if clade.branch_length == 0:
            clade.branch_length = 0.001  # Avoid zero length for branches

    return root







# Build the NJ tree
nj_tree = neighbor_joining(D, names)

print('NJ TREE:')


# Step 5a: Plot the NJ tree using matplotlib
def plot_phylo_tree(tree, title="Phylogenetic Tree"):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    axes = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    Phylo.draw(tree, do_show=False, axes=axes)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()  # Ensure the tree is displayed on the screen


# Plot the NJ tree
plot_phylo_tree(nj_tree, title="Neighbor Joining Tree")



# Import additional library for saving plots
import os

# Define the directory where you want to save the images
output_dir = "X:\\PROJECT\\trees"

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Function to save the NJ tree
def save_phylo_tree(tree, filename="NJ_tree.png", title="Phylogenetic Tree"):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    axes = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    Phylo.draw(tree, do_show=False, axes=axes)
    plt.title(title)
    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
    plt.savefig(output_path)
    plt.close(fig)



# Save the NJ tree
save_phylo_tree(nj_tree, filename="NJ_tree.png", title="Neighbor Joining Tree")


# After building the NJ tree
print("Final NJ Tree Structure:")
Phylo.draw_ascii(nj_tree)  # This will print a text representation of the tree to the console

print(nj_tree)

